# "return false" not stopping postback to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 view and in this view I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // My controls
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
}
```

What I want is to make an ajax call checking the record count prior to posting to the controller.

If the record count is high I want to stay on the view and prompt the user.

Everything appears to be working with the exception that the view is still posting to MyAction.   I would have expected "return false;" to prevent that.

Why is "return false" not stopping the post to the controller?

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {

        var p1= $("#Value1").val();
        var p2= $("#Value2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/MyController/GetRecordCount",
            data: { "param1": p1, "param2": p2 },
            async: false
        }).done(function (recCount) {
            if (recCount> 999)
            {
                $(".showAdditionalInfo").show();
                return false;
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
    });
```

Comment: The return false will occur after the ajax post happens

Comment: you will need to wrap the $.ajax call in an if-else loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return should be within the click handler itself. Right now it is inside of the AJAX callback.

It should be this instead:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var p1= $("#Value1").val();
        var p2= $("#Value2").val();
        var doPost = true;


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/MyController/GetRecordCount",
            data: { "param1": p1, "param2": p2 },
            async: false
        }).done(function (recCount) {
            if (recCount> 999)
            {
                $(".showAdditionalInfo").show();
                doPost = false;
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });

        return doPost;
    });
```

This assumes that the ajax request will not be async. Once it is then this shouldn't work anymore.

Comment: They return false will never allow the post to occur (in my case I want it to post if recCount is less then 999 records.

Comment: Okay I edited my answer. Basically, unless the AJAX request succeeds and the `recCount` is greater than 999 then a post back will occur. Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: That accomplishes what I need.  ty.